# unable to resolve service for type error for my controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, jwt

Edit: Camilo Terevinto's comment helped me to solve the issue. Removed primitives from controller constructor and it worked

I have added `services.AddControllers();` but it still gives me this error. Is there anything else i must do for dependency injection to work?

Error message

> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'System.String' while attempting to activate 'SarpunWebAPI.Controllers.TokenController'.
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, Boolean isDefaultParameterRequired)
> at lambda_method(Closure , IServiceProvider , Object[] )
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerActivatorProvider.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.b__0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerFactoryProvider.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.g__CreateController|0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
> at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
> at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.MigrationsEndPointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

TokenController.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using SarpunWebAPI.Data;
using JwtRegisteredClaimNames = System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtRegisteredClaimNames;

namespace SarpunWebAPI.Controllers
{
    public class TokenController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
        private readonly string _username;
        private readonly string _password;

        public TokenController(ApplicationDbContext context, string username, string password)
        {
            _context = context;
            this._username = username;
            this._password = password;
        }

        [Route("/token")]
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create(string username, string password)
        { 
            if (await IsValidUsernameAndPassword(username,password) == false)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
            else
            {
                return new ObjectResult(await GenerateToken(username));
            }
        } 

        private async Task<bool> IsValidUsernameAndPassword(string username, string password)
        {
            
            //TODO implement usermanager and  checkpassword
            // var user = await _usermanager.FindByEmailAsync(username);
            // return await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user,password);

            return await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                if (username == "*******" && password == "********")
                {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            });

              

 
        }

        private async Task<dynamic> GenerateToken(string username)
        {
            //var user = await _usermanager.FindByEmailAsync(username);

            //var roles = from ur in _context.UserRoles
            //            join r in _context.Roles on ur.RoleId equals r.Id
            //            where ur.UserId == user.Id 
            //            select new {ur.UserId, ur.RoleId, r.Name };

            return await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                // user.Id
                string user_id = "userId1";
                //roles
                List<Tuple<string, string, string>> roles = new List<Tuple<string, string, string>>()
            {
            new Tuple<string, string, string> ("userId1","role1","rolename1"),
            new Tuple<string, string, string> ("userId1","role2","rolename2")
            };


                var claims = new List<Claim>()
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, username),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier,user_id),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Nbf, new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now).ToUnixTimeSeconds().ToString()),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Exp, new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5)).ToUnixTimeSeconds().ToString())
            };

                foreach (var role in roles)
                {
                    //claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role.Name));
                    claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role.Item3));
                }

                var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
                    new JwtHeader(
                        new SigningCredentials(
                            new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("BUM BE YARAG")),
                            SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256)),
                        new JwtPayload(claims));

                var output = new
                {
                    Access_Token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token),
                    UserName = username
                };

                return output;
            });
            
                 
        }


    }
}
```

startup.cs

```
 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using SarpunWebAPI.Data;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.Text;

namespace SarpunWebAPI
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddControllers(); 
            
            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = "JwtBearer";
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "JwtBearer";

            })
                .AddJwtBearer("JwtBearer", jwtBearerOptions =>
                {
                    jwtBearerOptions.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("BUM BE YARAG")),
                        ValidateIssuer = false,
                        ValidateAudience = false,
                        ValidateLifetime = true,
                        ClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5)
                    };
                });
            services.AddSwaggerGen(setup =>
            {
                setup.SwaggerDoc(
                    "v1",
                    new Microsoft.OpenApi.Models.OpenApiInfo
                    {
                        Title = "Sarpun API",
                        Version = "v1"
                    });
            });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(x =>
            {
                x.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Sarpun API v1");
            });

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot inject primitives (like `string`): `TokenController(ApplicationDbContext context, string username, string password)`. Why don't you just remove that `username` and `password` parameters? You don't use the fields anyway

Comment: Well i didn't know that. I was planning to create my data libraries after i make the api work for the project. Thanks for the tip Camilo Terevinto

Comment: No problem. If you require some data in your Controllers (or any other service for that matter), take a look at this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-3.1